"It is too far down." VS "It is a long way down."
Imagine someone is trying to get down into the center of a volcano crater, and he is now standing around the edge of the crater. So, in order to mean the center is too far below where he is now, I would say:
It is too far down.
But I notice that native english speakers say:
"It is a long way down."
Does mine sound non-idiomatic or is it just a choice of native english speakers?

These don't mean the same thing at all. If something is "too far" then it is too far for something, such as too far to reach with your rope.

@DanielRoseman, I understand your point about "too far". How about "too far down"? Is it grammatically wrong or not natural?

It still needs something to be too far down for. Anything with "too" would need that. It doesn't just mean "very".

too far down means that it is past some preset limit ... long way down is just a measure of distance

Different in meaning. "A long way" means "very far", and "A long way down" is an idiomatic way to say that the crater is very deep. On the other hand "too far down" means that the depth is greater than is desirable or acceptable.
Something can be "too far" but not "very far".  My coffee is too far for me to reach, unless I stand up (but it's only about 1m away from me). On the other hand, the sun is "very far" away, but not "too far".  It's the perfect distance to keep Earth warm.
"It's too far down" is grammatically correct, but it doesn't mean "It's a long way down".
